# Can a deleted list item be restored to a different list?

Tags: restore, list-item

We have a couple list items deleted that we want to restore to collect attachments from, but we can't restore it to the same list if possible.

Comment: Check the recycle bin and restore it. Unfortunately you can restore only to the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do this. But you could restore it and then copy the list item to another list with powershell or code.